# Can I say “I wanna have a nice walk here?”

Tags: grammaticality

Can I say “I wanna have a nice walk here?” Is it an incorrect sentence or not?

Comment: This question is not good for this site. Maybe on ELL would be better. Also, wanna = want to and wanna is just a way to "say" it in spoken language.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

That is because mistranscribing *want to* as its [***eye-dialect*** spelling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eye_dialect) *wanna* marks the speaker as sloppy or illiterate. If you're transcribing dialect dialogue as Mark Twain or Charles Dickens so often did, then fine, but otherwise you should avoid it because it makes you look like you did not go to school, where writing that would have seen your submission marked down as incorrect in written English.

The other problem is that there are very few circumstances that would license *have a walk*. The normal collocation is *take a walk*. So it is possible but unlikely and unexpected to phrase it as you have. Even so, you should spell things in English as they are written, not as they are sounded.